# Pycharm Python build issue

Tags: python, pycharm, robotframework

**Pycharm**: 162.6262.63, **Python**: 3.7, **Robot**:3.1.1

My python scripts are not getting compiled properly (in Pycharm) which resulted in executing the previous code.

**Execution:-**

```
import robot
robot.run("tmp.robot",stdout=logFile)
```

**Robot Suite**:-

```
*** Settings ***
Resource            ../foo/boo/test.py

*** Test Cases ***    
Dry run    
[Documentation] foo
[Tags] foo    
printing_1
printing_2
```

**Python:-**

```
class test():
   def printing_1(self):
     print("Hello")

   def printing_2(self):
     print("Python")
```

**Results:-**

```
Hello
Python
```

But apparently, the **same results are produced** even after commenting some of the python lines as below.

**Python:-**

```
class test():
  def printing_1(self):
     print("Hello")

  def printing_2(self):
     pass
     # print("Python")
```

**Results:-**

```
Hello
Python
```

I am not sure why python compilation is not happening in pycharm. Could someone help what changes need to be done to get the latest changes reflected?

Comment: Running the same code via command line do you have the same issue?

Comment: @Giordano Yes, Getting same issue.

Comment: So probably is not a pycharm issue, but is code problem...

Comment: @Giordano It doesn't seem to be a code issue as I have checked thoroughly. If you see the given example, I have just commented a line in method 'printing2'. So results should be different.

Comment: The only possible explanations are that you aren't saving the changes, or that you're saving changes to a different file than the file being used by robot.

Comment: Does deleting the test.pyc file resolve it?

Comment: Deleting and creating the same file resolved the issue. Any idea why this issue would have occurred and how to resolve it in other way? as deleting will not be feasible all the times when number of files are gonna be huge in project. Kindly help.

Comment: Did you have write permission to the file? I once encountered something similar where I thought I saved the file after commenting out some lines but it didn't work. I fixed it by editing it in administrator mode ensuring the changes actually go through. This was on windows.

Comment: @JoonasKöppä I do have admin rights and having habit of saving file though auto save mode is on. Secondly, the same file has been used to write multiple functions for more than 3 months and issues encountered only today. So, I suspect, issue might be from pycharm. Note: Pycharm version was not changed today.

Comment: I am facing this issue once again for no reason. Looks to be pycharm issue.

Comment: Any assistance would be highly appreciated!!!!